# If loaded dynamically, SVG does not play animation on android and safari

Tags: android, animation, svg, safari

Here is the SVG part:

```
<svg id='canvBg' class='radar_canv' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' version='1.1' xmlns:xlink='http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink' style='z-index: 0' width='240' height='240'>
<defs>
<radialGradient id='backGrad' cx='50%' cy='50%' r='50%' fx='50%' fy='50%'>
<stop offset='0%' style='stop-color:rgb(0,190,0);stop-opacity:1'></stop>
<stop offset='100%' style='stop-color:rgb(0,140,0);stop-opacity:1'></stop>
</radialGradient>
</defs>
<circle id='radarBack' cx='50%' cy='50%' r='50%' stroke='rgb(50,240,50)' stroke-idth='2' fill='url(#backGrad)'></circle>
<line x1='50%' y1='0%' x2='50%' y2='100%' style='stroke-width:2;stroke:rgba(50,240,50,.7);'></line>
<line x1='0%' y1='50%' x2='100%' y2='50%' style='stroke-width:2;stroke:rgba(50,240,50,.7);'></line>
<text x='2%' y='49%' fill='navy' font-size='18'></text>
<g id='gg2'>
<rect x='50%' y='45%' width='50%' height='5%' fill='green'>
<animateTransform xlink:href='#gg2' attributeType='XML' attributeName='transform' type='rotate' from='0' to='45' dur='10s' fill='freeze' />
</rect>
</g>
</svg>
```

I load this piece of code to the `<body>` dynamically and it plays great on the PC, but it fails to run on my Android and iPhone's Safari. It loads the graphics, but won't play the animation.
The animation is played only when the SVG is embedded in the page from the beginning.

I've already tried to create all the elements via `createElementNS` with corresponding namespace and set the properties accordingly, but with no success.

What could be the reason and is there a solution for this?

P.S. Cannot use any external library, guys. Do not suggest.

Comment: Sounds like https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=82647 or https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=74801

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this will help you, but what I've done, and what appears to be working is to preload your svg "image" via the `subresource` relationship.

*haml*

`%link{ href: 'path/to.svg', rel: 'subresource'}`

*html*

`<link href="path/to.svg" rel="subresource"/>`

In my case, I use the svg as a background via CSS. Prior to subresourcing the resource, it would stop animating after a subsequent reload. This seems to fix it. It should also be noted that I'm using Angular 1.x (1.6.1 at the time of writing). This preloading allowed me to cleanly load the resource prior to the rest of the page which presumably gave the browser a chance to fully realize the resource before trying to display it and defaulting to a static image.

This is all of course speculation but I can't quite argue with results. Sorry it wasn't a more scientific answer. YMMV. Would love to hear if this works for others!

Read more about it here: https://css-tricks.com/prefetching-preloading-prebrowsing/ (the resource I used)